# Kafka consumer side decompression

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

My application is implemented in Java using Spring Boot. We are using Kafka for receiving messages from another application which is implemented in .net.

As the message size becomes bigger than 1 MB, from producer end, they have implemented compression. But after compression, messages are sent in byte format and at consumer end, we are getting "Message conversion Exception".

Should we need to decompress the message which is in byte ? I tried searching but I haven't found any decompression technique at consumer end using Java Spring Boot. Does anyone faced such scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

Messages are always sent as bytes. That's the responsibly of the serializer

Decompression is automatically done by the consumer. If you're getting an exception, it's caused by something else. For example, "message conversion" seems like a deserializer exception while taking the byte array to some POJO